# PhpStorm html class name folding

Tags: phpstorm

PhpStorm has great code folding features, but I need to know:
If there is any way to fold html classes names in code like style inline attribute values?

[image]

Because, If I'm going to use some libs like MDL, it could be alooooooot of unnecessary html class declarations and I want to keep it folded.

Like this one:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is no such option for `class` attribute collapsing -- only for HTML's 'style' attribute.

All available option can be found in `Settings/Preferences | Editor | General | Code Folding`

Consider submitting new Feature Request ticket to the Issue Tracker at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WEB (but check for existing tickets first).